# TypeError: Xjs("hi").getName is not a function showing in firebug console

Tags: javascript

Why is this code showing an error in Firebug?

```
var Xjs =function(name){
    if(!(this instanceof Xjs)) return new Xjs(name)
};
Xjs.prototype={
    constructor:Xjs,
    Xjs:function(){this.name=name;},
    getName:function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

In Firebug:

```
Xjs('hi').getName();
```

Comment: why i cannot access getName function ??

Comment: heyyy is there anyone who can help me?????????

Comment: hold on - I just got the entire stackoverflow users on this case, can take a while, there  are a few thousands people to coordinate, but we will get you there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Xjs =function(name){
    if(!(this instanceof Xjs)) return new Xjs(name)
    this.name = name;
};
Xjs.prototype={
    constructor:Xjs,
    getName:function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
Xjs('hi').getName();
```

You do not need to pass to methods in the prototype the `name` treat this as an object. The `name` is already available as `this.name` to all members of that object

Comment: thnx itay.but if i want to passs the 'name' to prototype den??

Comment: Show an example why you would like to do that.

Comment: like in above example if i want to pass the argument name in any function of prototype

Comment: @ankur: maybe add the line `setName: function (newName) { this.name = newName; }` ?

Comment: var Xjs =function(name){
    if(!(this instanceof Xjs)) return new Xjs(name)
};
Xjs.prototype={
    constructor:Xjs,
    abc:function(name){ //code goes here},
    getName:function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

Comment: well, the `getName()` is in the prototype and it works fine right now.

Comment: here is my new function abc() which uses the passed value 'name' is this is correct??

Comment: You do not need to pass the method the `name` treat this as an object. The name is already available as `this.name` to all members of that object.

Comment: @domenic:well then i have to call the setname function first ryt? this is not i want i want to use the value name in prototype thats it

Comment: @itay:thnx a lot itay i think i have understood most of it

Answer (score 0):

object fields must be members of the object itself not it's prototype try this:

```
var Xjs =function(name){
    if(!(this instanceof Xjs)) return new Xjs(name);
    this.name = name;        
};
Xjs.prototype={
    constructor:Xjs,   
    getName:function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: for cleaner solution, I would switch the lines `    this.name = name;
    if(!(this instanceof Xjs)) return new Xjs(name)`

Answer (score 0):

Itay's solution is correct.

To explain: it's a bit hard to tell what your line

```
    Xjs:function(){this.name=name;},
```

is supposed to be accomplishing, especially since the variable `name` is not defined at that point.

But if I had to guess, I'd say that seem to be under the impression that adding an `Xjs` function to `Xjs.prototype` will act as a constructor (somehow), and perhaps magically get wired to the original `Xjs` function which accepts a `name` parameter.

This is, needless to say, false. All that adding `Xjs : function () { this.name = name; }` to `Xjs.prototype` means, is that you could do the following:

```
var instance = new Xjs("hi");
instance.Xjs();
```

In other words, it adds another method to `Xjs` instances, just like `getName`, although that method happens to be confusingly named `Xjs`.

(Of course, that code would immediately throw a `ReferenceError` since, as mentioned, `name` is not defined. But that's a separate issue.)